# Conntrack empty within a Docker container

Tags: linux, iptables, docker, netfilter

Does anyone of you have experience with the use of `conntrack` in a containerized environment? I am running a regular alpine docker container with `docker run --network bridge --privileged --cap-add all -it --rm alpine` on a Debian operating system (kernel 5.10.0-6-amd64), however, `/proc/net/nf_conntrack` remains empty within the container, and `conntrack -L` returns 0 active connections despite the fact that I am initiating outgoing connections from within this container. I can see those open connections in the `conntrack` of the physical machine, but 0 within the container. Any solutions suggested to sort out that problem, i.e., to be able to list those connections using the `conntrack` within the container? Thanks in advance for any hints on how to accomplish that! I really want to see those active connections using the `conntrack` of the container! Here, I present a short demo of the functionality received.

```
host# docker run --network bridge --privileged --cap-add all -it --rm alpine
container# apk add screen
container# apk add ncftp
container# apk add conntrack-tools
container# screen
container/s1# ncftp ftp.de.debian.org
container/s2# conntrack -L -p tcp --dport 21
conntrack v1.4.6 (conntrack-tools): 0 flow entries have been shown.
host# conntrack -L -p tcp --dport 21
tcp      6 431889 ESTABLISHED src=172.17.0.2 dst=141.76.2.4 sport=50078 dport=21 packets=17 bytes=980 src=141.76.2.4 dst=192.168.190.230 sport=21 dport=50078 packets=15 bytes=1570 [ASSURED] mark=0 use=1
conntrack v1.4.6 (conntrack-tools): 1 flow entries have been shown.
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

```
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Executed from within the container will do the trick.

Comment: Why does this enable conntrack flows in the container's network namespace? It feels like more of a side-effect of creating the iptables rule, which begs the question - is there a way to directly enable conntrack flows without the iptables rule?